# Insert floppy img into virtual box

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

so I have been trying to insert a floppy disk image and supposedly you are supposed to go devices>floppy device>more images? But for me there is no floppy devices. Does any one know the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your VM settings, go to `Storage`, use `Add Controller` button and select `Add Floppy Controller`.  From that controller, you can `Add Floppy Device` and select the image.

[Here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage) is the relevant VirtualBox manual section.